# Very slow internet on wireless ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: internet

I am a new user to Ubuntu, dual boot System with Windows.
Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with a wireless adapter USB Asus Nano , the internet speed is very very slow. On other computer connected to the same wireless network internet is fine.
As I am a new user with no Linux experience I would appreciate simple step by step instructions.

Thank you